# This code does not run all the way through. I may have restricted privilege for ports but I am not sure how to test it

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;


    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

//Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    //Send some data
    message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");

    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);

    return 0;
}
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSaiI.png)

Comment: The IP-address you connect to doesn't respond to a tcp connection request on port 80. That's why it hangs after "Socket created". If you wait some minutes you will get the "connect error" because of the tcp connect timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output shows that your code passed the "`Socket created`", but didn't reach the "`Connected`". As you have no "`connect error`", `connect()` didn't yet fail.  As you have no abort either, it is highly probable that you're stuck waiting for the connection to be established.

One way to test it would be to try open the address directly in the browser with `http://<ip address>`  (equivalent to talking to port 80)

According to [this site](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/74.125.235.20), the address you are talking to belongs to google, but has its port 80 closed.  It is possible that security measures on google side make the rejection of the connection to be filtered.  THis could explain why you experience a long timeout instead of a quick failure message.

So another way to test your code would be to use the address of a valid http server.  TO find one, run your command line, type "ping google.com" and take the address that is displayed for the ping requests in your programme.  The connection will then succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from wikipedia:

> The range of port numbers from **1024 to 49151** are the registered ports.
>   They are assigned by IANA for specific service upon application by a
>   requesting entity.[1] On most systems, registered ports can be used by
>   ordinary users.

That means that any port bellow 1024 will not work as they are already assigned.

Comment: OP is not opening port 80 on his own PC, but is trying to connect to port 80 on the remote server. The code works very well with the address of an active and reachable web server.